# Cookies persisted only with React proxy

Tags: reactjs, django, http, cookies, proxy

#### Situation

I am using a cookie-based authentication system in my project - a *React* frontend application and a *Django* backend. Django runs on `localhost:8000` and React on `localhost:3000`.

According to [React Security Fundamentals](https://courses.reactsecurity.io/react-security-fundamentals) I needed to set `proxy` inside `package.json` to be able to make my cookies unaccessible via JavaScript.

In Django I simply `set_cookie` with the tokens I require (`httponly` set to `True` and `max_age` according to the token).

**Everything works up to this point.**

Recently I've started using Cypress for frontend testing and the `proxy` option inside `package.json` makes it impossible to mock requests.
Because of that I removed the `proxy` option.

#### Problem

I am no longer getting the cookies saved in the browser. Removing `httponly` flag doesn't fix it. The cookies are still being sent normally as I can still see them in *Postman*.

The only notable Django response header I can see in Postman is
`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` (seems not related).
There are no CORS headers specified whatsoever.

- What is the reason that the cookies are ignored by the browser?
- What is the most optimal way of storing session without React `proxy`?